# Data validation conditional between min and max values in different columns cells (with or without vba)

Tags: excel, validation, conditional-statements, excel-2010, vba

On Sheet 1 I have the min and max length of bird wings which is different for males and females, i.e. variables:

BirdID | WingMMin (Average minimum length of males) | WingMMax (Average max length of males).

On Sheet 2 I want to capture actual measurements for birds, but validated against Sheet 1 (The data captured, e.g. WingLength must be between WingMMin and WingMMax for the specific bird and sex using variables:

BirdID (No to be typed) | Sex (1= Male; 2=Female to be entered) | WingLength.

It seems to be too difficult to do this without VBA, but since I do not know VBA, I don't how to program this for all the values in the WingLength column. The logic should be as follows:

```
If Winglength <> between WingMMin and WingMMin) then
   Msgbox (The measurement is invalid. It should be between WingMMin and WingMMin)
End if
```

Comment: You can do this using [data validation with formulas in the min and max](http://www.excel-easy.com/basics/data-validation.html) or even [conditional formatting](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f). No need for VBA in this case.

Comment: If you want to use VLOOKUP,, VLOOKUP supports only one criterion, so you have to have a single value which contains both the bird id and the gender id: e.g. `=A5 & "_" & A6`. Then you can lookup on that single column. https://exceljet.net/formula/vlookup-with-two-or-more-criteria

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your worksheet structure looks like this:

> **Sheet1**
>
> ```
> A         B         C           D
> BirdID    Gender    WingMMin    WingMMax
> ```
>
> **Sheet2**
>
> ```
> A         B         C
> BirdID    Gender    WingLength
> ```

you could add columns to Sheet1 and Sheet2 with the following formula:

```
=A1 & "_" & B1
```

which would give a unique string for each bird-ID / gender combination. On Sheet1, this column should be before the `WingMin`/`WingMax` columns; we'll assume it's the third column.

> **Sheet1**
>
> ```
> A         B         C           D           E
> BirdID    Gender    UniqueID    WingMMin    WingMMax
> ```
>
> **Sheet2**
>
> ```
> A         B         C             D
> BirdID    Gender    WingLength    UniqueID
> ```

Then, you can use the `VLOOKUP` worksheet function to determine whether a particular line is valid:

```
=AND(C2 >= VLOOKUP(D2, Sheet1!$C$1:$E$100, 2, FALSE), C2 <= VLOOKUP(D2, Sheet1!$C$1:$E$100, 3, FALSE)
```

This function will return TRUE if the value is valid, and FALSE if it is invalid.

You can place this formula in an additional column, or you could apply conditional formatting based on the formula.